# Change object in an function

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I am in the process of coding some programm using Tkinter. The idea is to have a mainwindow which changes its content by pressing buttons. If the content changed I want to creat a "back" button (as known from many programms), which leads back to the mainwindow.

I thought about putting the window elements in functions, so that the "back" button will trigger the function to creat the mainwindow. However, if I for example press the "settings" button, I want the content of the mainwindow to disappear to make room for the new stuff. The problem is, that those elements I want to delete, or grid.forget() are in a different function and therefor local variables. Is there any way to alter them?

here some code example:

```
"""Import"""
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import datetime
import json as js
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

"""Global variables"""
ACTIVATED = False



"""Functions"""

def main_window():

    global canvas, image

    root.configure(bg="white", padx=50, pady=50)
    canvas.destroy()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(width=100, height=100, bg="white", highlightthickness=0)
    resized_image = image.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
    logo = canvas.create_image((50, 50), image=image)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan = 4)

    title = tk.Label(text="TEXT", bg="white", width=6, font=("Edwardian Script ITC", 50,))
    title.grid(row=0, column=5, columnspan = 6, sticky = tk.E)

    empty = tk.Label(text="", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), bg="white", pady=10,)
    empty.grid(row=1, column=1)

    settings_button = tk.Button(text="Settings", command=settings)
    settings_button.grid(row=2, column=0)

    analyse_button = tk.Button(text="Analyse data", command=analyse)
    analyse_button.grid(row=2, column=1)


def settings():

    settings_button.grid.forget()
    analyse_button.grid.forget()
   
    back_button = tk.Button(text="back", command=main_window)
    back_button.grid(row=2, column=1)

    some new stuff
```

thanks for your kind advices.

Comment: Maybe use a more Object Oriented approach?

Comment: Normally, it makes more sense to put the controls you want to be able to hide in some sort of container (like a panel) you can temporarily hide and later show again. That way you don't have to reconstruct everything part by part over and over. The window, panel, controls, etc. are all objects so they remember their internal state as long as you don't really throw them away. Apart from that, do you think it makes the most sense to keep changing a single window? Do other applications do that? Would users expect it? Like @bruno says, look at object orientation, but also at how other apps work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend wrapping your main window into a class instead of handling it through functions only. Create an instance of your class. You can access all elements you want to hide or show etc. through its attribute `self.<element>`.

I slightly modified your code to look like this:

```
"""Import"""
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import datetime
import json as js
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class myClass():

    """Functions"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.ACTIVATED = False

        self.root.configure(bg="white", padx=50, pady=50)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=100, height=100, bg="white", highlightthickness=0)
        self.resized_image = image.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
        self.logo = canvas.create_image((50, 50), image=image)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan = 4)

        self.title = tk.Label(text="TEXT", bg="white", width=6, font=("Edwardian Script ITC", 50,))
        self.title.grid(row=0, column=5, columnspan = 6, sticky = tk.E)

        self.empty = tk.Label(text="", font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), bg="white", pady=10,)
        self.empty.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.settings_button = tk.Button(text="Settings", command=settings)
        self.settings_button.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.analyse_button = tk.Button(text="Analyse data", command=analyse)
        self.analyse_button.grid(row=2, column=1)


    def settings(self):

        self.settings_button.grid.forget()
        self.analyse_button.grid.forget()
   
        self.back_button = tk.Button(text="back", command=main_window)
        self.back_button.grid(row=2, column=1)

        some new stuff

myObject = myClass()

#call when needed
myObject.settings()
```

[This article](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-hide-recover-and-delete-tkinter-widgets/) only somewhat relates to your issue, but it demonstrates the concept fairly well.

Edit: What Grismar said in his comment, i.e. change/rewrite the whole structure, is a very good point, and most definitely the right solution in the long term. I aim to keep your structure and work with that. I have to note though, that I fully agree with Grismars opinion!

Comment: You are right, I didn t see that myself. All the functionality of my code is allready inside objects, I don t know why I didn t see this solution myselfe... Thanks